# how to run a java program by double clicking it

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new for java. As a first step, I made a simple calculator in `NetBeans`.

I wanted to make it an executable software and to run it just by double clicking it as on visual basic.

Please tell me if you know a method to do that.

Comment: Double click on the compiled jar?

Comment: For Windows you could create an exe File Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your IDE but you need to export an as executable jar file. Then you can run that.

In Eclipse:

> File > Export > Runnable Jar File > Choose your path > Click export

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project -> Clean and build

You can find the runnable jar in your project folder > dist (newly created folder)